# How to get selected objects from NSArrayController without a proxy object?

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller, nspasteboard, nsproxy

I am trying to implement copying and pasting of multiple objects in an `NSTableView` backed by an `NSArrayController`. My `copy:` method looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)copy:(id)sender {
    if (self.arrayController.selectionIndexes.count > 0) {
        NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        [pasteboard clearContents];
        NSArray *copiedObjects = self.arrayController.selection;
        [pasteboard writeObjects:copiedObjects];
    }
}
```

When I try to perform a copy I get an error accessing the controller's selection because it returns a proxy object:

```
-[_NSControllerObjectProxy countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88b362d580
```

How can I get the actual selected objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is incredibly obvious: use `self.arrayController.selectedObjects` instead.